# Establecer la fecha actual como fecha minima en datetime picker con C#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

Soy un programador novato y no suelo usar este tipo de plataformas para resolver mis dudas, pero me encontre con este problema. Necesito establecer como fecha minima de un DateTimePicker la fecha actual, con el objetivo de que el usuario no pueda elegir fechas anteriores, pero he buscado y no encontre la manera. Agradeceria que alguien con mas experiencia pueda ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: Buen Día, te recomiendo que te des una vuelta a [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que puedas elaborar una buena pregunta y que nuestros compañeros puedan ayudarte.  Y se pueda limitar tu pregunta ya que la respuesta correcta puede variar.

Comment: Podrias contarnos que fue lo que buscaste?? tal vez podriamos ayudarte a buscar mejor (esto esta en la documentacion del control)

Comment: Busque en google, pero me aparecian en mayoria cosas que no eran lo que necesitaba, y no sabia que existia la documentacion, como aclare soy muy nuevo. Gracias por la informacion y por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El control datetimepicker tiene una propiedad para establecer [MinDate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate?view=windowsdesktop-5.0).
Puedes establecerla de la siguiente manera:

```
//fecha personalizada:
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(1985, 6, 20);

//fecha actual:
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Today;
```